# Python strip function removes 'e' letter as well from end of string

Tags: python, string, strip

I am using Python's strip method to remove a substring from string. Below is the example.

```
test = "router_sdkf12e"
print(test.strip("router_"))
```

Output : `sdkf12`

Issue : 'e' from the end of string is getting remove. However if there is some other letter other than 'e', then that letter is not removed. Why such weird behavior?

```
test = "router_sdkf12a"
print(test.strip("router_"))
```

Output : `sdkf12a`

Regards,
Rahul Kumbhar

Comment: given the string `"router_sdkf12z"` - what is your expected output?

Comment: `strip` removes the *characters* `eortu_` from either side of the string. It removes a set of **characters**, not the *substring* "router_".

Comment: `print(text.removeprefix("router_"))`

Comment: the only nuissance is that `removeprefix` came with Python 3.9, won't work in earlier versions

Comment: Before 3.9 `if text.startswith("router_"): text = text[7:]`

Comment: strip command removes `characters`(!) in the end of the string which are provided as "router_". So the last letter in result will be which is in the source string but not in ['r', 'o', 'u', 't', 'e', '_']. Ex. if you provide `router_sdkf12ero_ut` the result will be `sdkf12` as well. To remove a substring please use test.replace("router_", "")